# can't seem to get MongoDB find() with regex to work using PHP

Tags: regex, mongodb

I am fairly new to MongoDB (I've read the documentation)

Here is example of my data:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("53297684786d226f57ecbd60"),
"country" : "US", 
"short_state" : "FL", 
"state" : "Florida", 
"zip" : "33169", 
"city" : "Miami", 
"slug" : "miami-fl", 
"search_terms" : "miami fl miami florida" 
}
```

I am trying to match (similar to MySQL LIKE '%term%') search term...I TRIED:

- db.geo_table.find({search_terms : /^miami fl/i}); - MATCHES
- db.geo_table.find({search_terms : /^miami florida/i}) - DOES NOT
  MATCH
- db.geo_table.find({search_terms : /^miami florida.*/i}); -
  DOES    NOT MATCH
- db.geo_table.find({search_terms : /^florida/i}); -    DOES NOT
  MATCH
- db.geo_table.find({search_terms : /^*.miami    florida*./i}); - NO MATCH EITHER

basically how can i get regex to match any variation of my search_terms?
like, *miami*, *iami fl*, *ami flori*, *miami flo*, and so on..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your REGEX, you are using the `^` to say that the expression needs to be evaluated from the beginning.  For your string:

```
miami fl miami florida
```

This one evaluates true because the term `miami fl` does in fact appear at the beginning of the string.

```
db.geo_table.find({search_terms : /^miami fl/i}); - MATCHES
```

Every other variation of your REGEX does not appear at the beginning of the string since immediately after your `fl`, you have a space.

If you want to get the rest to match, remove the anchor and then do your match:

```
db.geo_table.find({search_terms : /miami florida/i});
```